# Renomear arquivos em lote usando Windows Power Shell

Tags: powershell

Como renomear todos os arquivos de uma pasta cujo nome seja um número (inteiro) seguido de uma determinada extensão (a minha escolha) usando o **Windows Power Shell**?

> Exemplo: A pasta como está:

```
1.txt
2.txt
7.txt
arquivo.html
```

> Como deve ficar depois da renomeação:

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
file7.txt
arquivo.html
```

Comment: Boa noite Ricardo, estamos discutindo esta pergunta aqui http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4516/3635

Comment: Parece que eu havia me enganado +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode resolver o problema combinando os cmdlets [Get-ChildItem](https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ee176841.aspx) para listar os arquivos do diretorio e [Rename-Item](https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/hh849763.aspx) para renomea-los

```
$raiz = "c:\ps"
$arquivos = Get-ChildItem $raiz  -Filter "*.txt" | Where-Object {$_.Name -match "^\d"} 
foreach($item in $arquivos){
    Rename-Item -NewName ("novo"+$item.Name) -Path ($raiz+$item.Name)
}
```

A primeira parte da linha filtra todos os arquivos com extensão `.txt`, a segunda parte pega o retorno(pipe) do cmdlet e aplica um regex no nome do arquivo ela diz para capturar apenas os arquivos que os nomes comecem com algum número e terceira parte é a atribuição dos arquivos selecionados para serem renomeados.

`Rename-Item` altera o nome do arquivo com o prefixo "novo" seguido do nome antigo(que era um número)

```
$arquivos = Get-ChildItem $raiz  -Filter "*.txt" | Where-Object {$_.Name -match "^\d"} 
|3 parte    |1 parte                             |2 parte
```

Answer (score 5):

Suponha que você tem um diretório com nomes de arquivo corrompidos. Você só sabe que todos eles são arquivos .png, mas as extensões foram trocadas para nomes aleatórios. Você gostaria então de renomear tudo para .png, de uma vez só.

Usando Windows PowerShell:

```
 dir | % {ren $_ ($_.name.substring(0, $_.name.length-4) + ‘.png’ ) }
```

O primeiro comando, dir, obtém uma lista de arquivos do diretório atual e passa objetos (não texto!) para o próximo comando no pipeline. O próximo então (o % significa foreach-object) executa o bloco (entre { e } ) para cada um dos ítens.

Nesse caso, o comando rename passando o nome `($_)` e o nome novo `($_.name.substring(0, $_.name.length-4) + ‘.png’ )`

Fonte: http://www.purainfo.com.br/programacao-scripts/power-shell/renomando-arquivos-em-massa-pelo-power-shell/

Answer (score 3):

Utilizei o seguinte comando para renomear todos os arquivos de determinada pasta e de determinada extensão:

```
Dir *.txt | ForEach-Object  -begin { $count=1 }  -process { rename-item $_ -NewName "$count.txt"; $count++ }
```

É necessário que esteja na pasta que deseja renomear os arquivos.

OBS: Não distingue nomes composto por números.

Comment: Legal, nunca usei PowerShell estou testando aqui parece que funciona. +1 ainda não consegui reproduzir exatamente do jeito que fez, mas vou estudar :)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento olha eu também não conheço o powershell, tive a necessidade de renomear arquivos em lote (com alguns requisitos específicos que não era possível somente com o explorer) então pesquisei e encontrei o powershell e achei interessante trazer o conteúdo para cá.

Answer (score -3):

Seguindo a dica do Otto, com alguma alteração, ficou assim:

dir | % {ren $_ ($*.name.substring(0, $*.name.length) + ‘.png’ ) }

Com esta sintese de comando consegui colocar a extensão "jpg" em arquivos que estavam sem extensão e por fim coseguir visualizá-los.